# linking agent location parameters to another agent

Tags: anylogic

We are trying to create a generic moving capability for our agents that way we can use this capability in many projects.

The way I thought to do it was to create an agent called move and use it as a member in each agent I have in the future. (I would have wanted to use it as the upper class but since Java can only use one class as a parent this is not possible).

The problem is that when preforming the moveTo() command in the move agent it does not move the spacial coordinates of the owner agent. 
Is it possible to link the two parameters so that any time x,y,z change in move agent the x,y,z in the owner agent also change?

Comment: Hi Chana, this is really badly phrased and unclear, sorry. Can you clarify, add screenshots... What is the problem, what did you try to fix it and what solution do you want? Also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right you want to have more control over your agent movements and have some custom logic you want to apply to all moveTo blocks. In that case it's easier to create a [custom flowchart](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_ProcessModeling%2FCustom_Block.html) for your move than trying to modify your agents. You can use your custom move (instead of moveTo) every time you need to move any agent.

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer. i am using state charts for the movement so my movement is custom. a better way to phrase the question might be: how can i make a link between two agents so that the movement of one agent automatically moves the other agent?